Forcing const arrays of pointers to const arrays into read-only memory with gcc? ('causes a section type conflict')
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__ ((section(".text"))) static const int one[2] = { 1, 2 };
__attribute__ ((section(".text"))) static const int two[2] = { 3, 4 };

static const int* parent[2] = { one, two };

If I place the array 'parent' above in .text I get this error:
sections.c:5:54: error: parent causes a section type conflict with one

This appears to be because the addresses of one and two, although known at link time, are being considered as if they were variables - and therefore parent is being initialised at run time, which means it is placed in RAM.  However the system I am compiling for is a small 8-bit micro with very little RAM and so I need to put not only simple const arrays in ROM (actual literal EPROM), but also arrays of arrays, where the elements are the base addresses of the simpler arrays which were successfully placed in a ROM segment.
Programs for this environment execute at a fixed address so there are no complicating issues such as relocatable code or a linking loader that may put code at some random address - the code in EPROM is fixed at address 0000.
What can I do to force these const arrays of const arrays to be placed in read-only memory?
Although the target system is a 6809 micro, I'm relatively confident you do not need to look for a 6809-specific explanation or workaround - it's a generic gcc problem and I believe a solution that would work on i686 or arm linux would work just as well for my environment (which is the Vectrex video game console).
I have looked at other answers here concerning the 'causes a section type conflict' error, but none offered an answer relevant to the problem of initialising const arrays with data that the compiler/linker ought to know the address of. If I compile without the section attribute, it does compile but it places those specific arrays in RAM and the linker warns ?ASlink-Warning-Size limit exceeded in bank ram and of course it fails at runtime.
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i, j, k=0;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      k += parent[i][j];
    }
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "tot = %d\n", k);
  return 0;
}


Maybe .rodata instead of .text?

Nope, tried that, same result.

You probably want static const int* const parent[2] = { one, two }; since you want your parent[] array to be const.

Thank you pmacfarlane, at the end of the day your suggestion contributed to a working solution, which was: `attribute ((section(".text"))) static const int one[2] = { 1, 2 };
attribute ((section(".text"))) static const int two[2] = { 3, 4 };
attribute ((section(".text"))) static const int* const parent[2] = { one, two };
int main(void) {
int i, j, k=0;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
k += parent[i][j];
}
}
return 0;
}
` (remembering that this is for the 6809 compiler generating code for the Vectrex)

The normal way to do it on most compilers is to declare the variable to be allocated in ROM as a read-only variable. With pointers, that is done like this:
static const int* const parent[2] = { one, two };

However, if you are short on flash/eeprom then this is probably not the best idea since the addresses in the array will take up extra space - and for what gain? You really should consider allocating a 2D array instead, if possible.

No, the reverse: we have up to 48K of directly addressible ROM space on this platform, but less than 800 bytes of free RAM.  Every possible byte of RAM than can be saved is worth having, for most applications.  That was why it was galling to have const arrays of pointers taking up RAM space.  (const arrays of simple scalars were not a problem)

@GrahamToal The question is what good the pointer array is doing you, instead of simply const int array [2][2] = {...};


I can't replicate the error.
You will get the warning in assembly as gcc instead of generating section .text much longer line.
To workaround it you need to use .text# section (mind the # which will comment the not needed part of the line in the assembly output

https://godbolt.org/z/bYGb6zo6e
